# neo4j server start but stopped immediately

Tags: neo4j

OS: Ubuntun 20.04.4 LTS with all latest updates/upgrades.

Issue:

Start neo4j server with: `sudo neo4j start`. And quickly the neo4j server process stopped.

The `neo4j.log` has the following lines:

```
2022-05-16 22:32:27.180+0000 INFO  Starting...
2022-05-16 22:32:29.849+0000 INFO  This instance is ServerId{f26a3f16} (f26a3f16-e633-4da0-9d4c-fd97ec6c324f)
2022-05-16 22:32:36.002+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.4.7 ========
2022-05-16 22:32:47.577+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on 0.0.0.0:7474.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting Neo4j database server at /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:228) ~[neo4j-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:181) ~[neo4j-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseManagementServiceFactory.createManagementService(EnterpriseManagementServiceFactory.java:38) ~[neo4j-enterprise-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseBootstrapper.createNeo(EnterpriseBootstrapper.java:20) ~[neo4j-enterprise-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:142) [neo4j-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:95) [neo4j-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint.main(EnterpriseEntryPoint.java:24) [neo4j-enterprise-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry@6060146b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Argument `params` at position 3 in `when` with
type `Map` cannot be converted to a Neo4j type: Default value `` could not be parsed as a MAP?".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:463) ~[neo4j-common-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110) ~[neo4j-common-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:219) ~[neo4j-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.exceptions.ProcedureException: Argument `params` at position 3 in `when` with
type `Map` cannot be converted to a Neo4j type: Default value `` could not be parsed as a MAP?
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.MethodSignatureCompiler.signatureFor(MethodSignatureCompiler.java:108) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureCompiler.compileProcedure(ProcedureCompiler.java:252) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureCompiler.compileProcedure(ProcedureCompiler.java:226) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProcedures(ProcedureJarLoader.java:122) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:96) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry.start(GlobalProceduresRegistry.java:371) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:442) ~[neo4j-common-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110) ~[neo4j-common-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:219) ~[neo4j-4.4.7.jar:4.4.7]
    ... 6 more
2022-05-16 22:32:47.624+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2022-05-16 22:32:47.627+0000 INFO  Stopped.
```

Any help?